# how to return an xml node and get a .text() from its children?

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm pretty new with Jquery. I'm trying to do a plugging that retrieves info from several pages.
I do an ajax call and get an xml, then I want to select a specific text of one node, xmlc looks like this:

```
<status>
  <item>
    <name>NameA</name>
    <serviceUrl>theURL</serviceUrl>
    <timeout>184</timeout>
    <errorMessage></errorMessage>
    <statusMessage>SpecificMessage</statusMessage>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>NameB</name>
    <serviceUrl>theURL</serviceUrl>
    <timeout>200</timeout>
    <errorMessage></errorMessage>
    <statusMessage>SpecificMessageB</statusMessage>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>NameC</name>
    <serviceUrl>theURL</serviceUrl>
    <timeout>300</timeout>
    <errorMessage></errorMessage>
    <statusMessage>SpecificMessageC</statusMessage>
  </item>
</status>
```

and my code that i can't make work is:

```
    function parseXml(xml)
{
    item = getItemFor(xml, "NameB");
    console.log("name: " + item.find("name").text());
    console.log("serviceUrl: " + item.find("serviceUrl").text());
    console.log("timeout: " + item.find("timeout").text());
}

var getItemFor= function(xml, name){
    $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
        var itName = $(this).find("name").text();
        if (itName === name){
            console.log("Found: " + name);
            return $(this);
        }


    });
}
```

bottom line, I can't get the xml item NODE with name nameB out of the getItemFor function and i also can't stop the .each() looping.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: sorry for that, taking note for the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is modifying your `getItemFor` function to pass result returned from the inner loop:

```
var getItemFor = function(xml, name) {
    var result = null;
    $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
        var itName = $(this).find("name").text();
        if (itName === name) {
            console.log("Found: " + name);
            result = $(this);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Or simplify `parseXml` completely (reducing to one selector):

```
function parseXml(xml) {

    var item = $('item name:contains("NameB")', xml).parent();

    console.log("name: " + item.find("name").text());
    console.log("serviceUrl: " + item.find("serviceUrl").text());
    console.log("timeout: " + item.find("timeout").text());
}
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NUsY9/).

Comment: I liked the 2nd option. I also was looking for a simplified way. Thanks!!

Comment: Beware that the 2nd option is looking for names **containing** NameB.. That means that NameBCD would also fit. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501271/944681) for fix.