# jQuery li find the exact equal

Tags: jquery

###HTML

```
<ul id="thiselement">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>timer</li>
    <li>check</li>
    <li>ramramesh</li>
    <li>ramesh</li>
</ul>
```

###jQuery

```
document.write($("#thiselement li:not(:contains('ramesh'))").text());
```

###Expected result

```
testtimercheckramramesh
```

###What I am getting

```
testtimercheck
```

How can I achieve this?  I understand that `contains` will return where ever it finds the text but I need only the exact text selector, since I want to use the each function with the result

```
$("#thiselement li:not(:contains('ramesh'))").each(function(){});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rGyKK/)

Comment: ramramesh contains ramesh

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501228/jquery-contains-function-limit-to-exact-match

Comment: @ohaal pls note I want to use it in the li each function that's not suitable one

Comment: Why it is not suitable? You could still use each loop

Comment: @mplungjan I understand that but I want to omit like that case, I want to search the exact text

Comment: @roasted can you give some example for my case? I want to apply some css other then ramesh but I want to apply the css to ramramesh

Comment: See doc, they are some examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/dntAU/2/

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text()
    if ( text == 'ramesh'){
      alert(text + " is ramesh ")   
    }else{
    alert(text + " is not ramesh ");
    }
});

$('#thiselement li:contains("ramesh")').filter(
    function(){
        if( $(this).text() == 'ramesh'){
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
    });
```

Comment: is there any selecter available like contains to select equal value?

Comment: thanks for your effort, I need to add the class other then ramesh already I voted your answer

Comment: Thanks vinothini I have expected some more optimized way of result, if you found any other solution update that

Answer (score 5):

```
var names = $('ul li').map(function() {
    if ( $(this).text() !== 'ramesh' ) return $(this).text();
}).get().join();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3LKd/

Comment: but i missed some thing.I am unable to find it out.Can u help me to find that

Comment: You are joining DOM Element Objects.:)

Comment: @Thirumalai murugan  try this once

Answer (score 0):

Extended to vinothini answer is follows [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dntAU/4/) , still I am expecting some other possibility

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text()
    if ( text == 'ramesh'){
      alert(text + " is ramesh ")   
    }else{
    alert(text + " is not ramesh ");
    }
});

$('#thiselement li').filter(
    function(){
        if( $(this).text() != 'ramesh'){
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
    });


$('#thiselement li').each(
    function(){
        if( $(this).text() != 'ramesh'){
            $(this).addClass('back');
        }
    });
```

CSS

```
.highlight {
    color: white;
}

.back{background:blue;}
```