# jQuery :contains selector alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I would like to select an option in a drop down menu by its' text. When I run the code,:

`var theText = "Large";
$("#size option:contains(" + theText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');`

it selects XLarge instead of Large. Is there any way to make it select Large? JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r8wuP/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery :contains function limit to exact match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501228/jquery-contains-function-limit-to-exact-match) and [make jQuery's `:contains()` select only exact string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/make-jquerys-contains-select-only-exact-string)

Comment: `$("#size option").prop('selected', function() { return $(this).text() === theText; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to find an exact match, [:contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) returns partial matches also

```
var theText = "Large";
$("#size option").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == theText;
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nLL72/)

Comment: This answer is correct, so Arun had the correct answer first :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8wuP/3/

```
$('#size').find('option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'Large';
}).first().attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using 1.4 this would work:

```
var theText = "Large";
$("#size").find("option[text='" + theText + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

However later jQuery versions might need the filter method.