# Alternative to jQuery contains() Selector - is there an is() or equals() Selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Caveat: I'm not a developer, I'm a designer.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441763/667903) I learned of the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

I used this selector like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("td:contains('No')").css("background-color", "#FFBFBF");
});
```

However, this selects `td` cells containing `Not`, which I don't want to happen.

I found there is a `.filter()` selector from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22272136/667903), but I'm not a programmer, and do not understand how to apply `.filter()` to my jQuery code, so I'm wondering if there is something that functions like an `is()` or `equals()` selector?

Comment: @AndrewL that method has nothing to do with text matching

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using complex solutions, simply use `.not()` to deselect elements containing `'Not'` or any other word don't wanna include ;-)

```
.not(":contains('Not')")
```

Your code should look something like this...

```
jQuery("td:contains('No')").not(":contains('Not')").css("background-color", "#FFBFBF");
```

Here's a snippet...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("td:contains('No')").not(":contains('Not')").css("background-color", "#FFBFBF");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> What for breakfast today? </h3>
<table border=1 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td>Tea</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Coffee</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange juice</td>
    <td>Yeah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Champagne</td>
    <td>Not for breakfast!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This uses simple `.not()` method to unselect the elements with `Not`.

Comment: No need for complex hacky solutions :-)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For an absolute match using `filter()`:

```
jQuery("td").filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).text().trim() === 'No';
}).css("background-color", "#FFBFBF");
```

Comment: adding a class with style would be more clean right?rather than applying straight forward css using jquery it would be more flexible. but nonetheless perfect answer :)

Comment: Yes...also easier to reverse by removing class and not have to parse inline styles

Comment: Hi Charlie. I replaced my original code with your code and unfortunately `<td>No</td>` are not being given a `background-color: #FFBFBF;`

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/oefrg1tn/. Make sure elements exist when you run the code

Comment: That's odd. Code is run inside `jQuery(document).ready(function() {}` and there are definitely `<td>s` [containing 'No`](https://i.imgur.com/P999SbD.png).

Comment: I assume so. The code runs in the `<head>`, the `<td>`'s are created in the `<body>`.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, I added a bounty to this question if you can help me determine why your solution is not working in my environment.

Comment: As you have mentioned in your previous comment 'jQuery' instead of the dollar sign, have you replaced all of them in this snippet?

Comment: Edited my solution and switched `$` to `jQuery` ... try that. Look in browser console for any errors

Answer (score 1):

There is no such selector by default, but you can build your own, and `filter` the things in the way you want.

#### How to add a new selector

`jQuery.expr[":"]` is an object containing the available selectors (e.g. `:visible`, `:checked` and lots others). Here you want to add a new selector. So, in that case, the selector name will be the key, and the value will be a function receiving in the first argument the element.

If this function returns `true`, the element is matched, otherwise (if it's `false`), the element is *not* matched.

For example, this is the `:checked` definition:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].checked = function (el) {
   return el.checked === true;
};
```

#### Adding `:containsExact`

Simply, `extend` or append directly the method in the `jQuery.expr[":"]` object:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].containsExact = function (el, textToSearch) {
   return el.textContent === textToSearch;
};
```

#### Example

```js
// Add the containsExact selector
jQuery.expr[":"].containsExact = function(el, index, args) {
  return el.textContent === args[3];
};

// Highlight the spans containing "Mars" in red
jQuery("span:containsExact('Mars')").css("background", "#F82125");

// Highlight "Hello World" in yellow
jQuery("span:containsExact('Hello World')").css("background", "#F5C700");

// Highlight the "Hello Mars" (without exclamation mark) in blue
jQuery("span:containsExact('Hello Mars')").css("background", "#0696DE");
```

```css
span {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #293E51;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><span>Hello</span> <span>World</span></span><br>
<span><span>Hello</span> <span>Mars</span></span><br>
<span><span>Hello</span> <span>Mars</span></span>!<br>
<span><span>Hello</span> <span>Mars</span>!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got all the `td` tags on a simple JSP page I created to change to the appropriate color using the following code. (This code was placed inside the head section of my JSP page within script tags)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").each(function(){
        if($(this).html() == 'No')
        {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFBFBF");
        }
    });
});
```

All that I am doing here is this

1. Selecting all the `td` tags on my page
2. Checking if the text inside the `td` is No
3. If yes, change it to the appropriate color. If no, just ignore it