# Add Class to div if it contains Exact number

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="numb">1</div>
<div class="numb">2</div>
<div class="numb">3</div>
<div class="numb">4</div>
<div class="numb">5</div>
```

I need to get an Ouput like this for example : `<div class="numb four-stars">4</div>`

I tried this JS :

```
if ($(".numb").text().trim() === "4") {
    $(".numb").addClass('four-stars');
}
```

I made a mistake ?

Comment: $(".numb") selects all the elements with the class. When you use text() it will read the text from the FIRST element in the jquery collection. Hence why your code will not work.

Comment: @epascarello just for completeness, `$(".numb").text()` will read *all* of them, giving, in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/otyuskz3/) case `"12345"`.   Still won't work though :)

Comment: Similar answer, slightly different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462608/2181514  (need to know about `:contains`)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to loop through each `.numb` element and check its text value individually. To do that you can use `filter()`, like this:

```js
$('.numb').filter((i, el) => +el.textContent.trim() === 4).addClass('four-stars');
```

```css
.four-stars { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numb">1</div>
<div class="numb">2</div>
<div class="numb">3</div>
<div class="numb">4</div>
<div class="numb">5</div>
```