# How to change table tr TD value change query

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table and want to change the `data-title="Status"` value.

For Example : data-status text is DataSubmission means need to change the value as 'Inprogress'

Below the code please check:

```
$("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:contains('DataSubmission')").html("In Progress");
```

If data-title="Status  - text value is empty or blank we want to change the value 'Available'

```
$("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:contains('')").html("Available");
```

This the code :

```
<table class="inbox appList" cellspacing="0" data-openonpick="False" id="cpC_gvSearchResult" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
   <thead>
      <tr class="inboxHeader">
         <th data-field="ApplicationId" scope="col"> Id</th>
         <th data-field="ApplicantFirstName" scope="col">First Name</th>
         <th data-field="CurrentQueue" scope="col">Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="inboxRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">1</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">DataSubmission</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inboxAltRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">2</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inboxRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">3</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">DataSubmission</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inboxAltRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">4</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
var rowCount = $("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr").length;
alert(rowCount);
for(var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
{
  var status = $("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr").find("td:eq(3)").text();
  if(status =="DataSubmission" )
  {
     $("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:contains('DataSubmission')").html("In Progress");
  }
  else
  {
     $("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:contains('')").html("Available");
  }
    
}
```

Live:[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/mqg8h7Lv/1/)

Comment: Aaa this is  'a bit ' unclear. The requirement and the code you posted aswell. Can you please re-write your question ? You have 3 columns in each row. Each col has a `data-status` attribute. You want to change that attribute ? or the text inside the column depending on it's `data-status` attribute ?

Comment: @MihaiT Yes Correct data-status  text is DataSubmission means need to change the value as 'Inprogress'

Comment: Using jQuery: ```$('element').data('title', 'in progress')``` sets ```data-title``` to 'in progress'.
Question, what is your reasoning for using ```$.html()``` when setting a text string? Just use ```$.text()```.

Comment: So you just want to change the value of the `data-status` ? or the text inside the column with `data-status` DataSubmission ? Because nowhere in the code you posted are you selecting the `data-status` value.

Comment: @Lalalena Can you modify my Fiddle code

Comment: @MihaiT i want to change  text inside the column with data-status DataSubmission

Comment: No `td`s have `data-status='datasubmissions`

Comment: Having a guess at what you want (being picking in comment above) - you have two issues: 1) `$("#id tr")` will get all rows, so `td:eq(n)` will always find just the first one (as it's tds across all rows not just the one in the loop)  2) you want td eq(2) as it's 0-based, so (2) = 3rd col.  https://jsfiddle.net/pyfxLc2w/

Comment: @freedomn-m  data-status text value is empty also wants to update Available

Comment: It's still unclear.
Eg. You have `<td data-title="Status"> DataSubmission</td>` You want to change this into `<td data-title="Status"> In Progress</td>`  ?

Comment: @IvinRaj One problem is this `.find("td:eq(3)")` you don't have 4 td in each tr, you only have 3. Remember that it's 0 index based. So 0 is first, 1 is second and so on

Comment: Yes Correct @MihaiT . you are correct .. and one more thing if Status column is empty want to change this into <td data-title="Status"> Available</td>

Comment: @IvinRaj is this what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/cga24fjp/

Comment: Note: `:eq(n)` is now deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit unclear what you want to do or why . But here's a solution.

```js
const tdStatusCols = $("table tbody td[data-title='Status']")
$(tdStatusCols).each(function() {
  const statusText = $(this).text().trim()
  if ( statusText === 'DataSubmission' ) {
      $(this).text("In Progress" )
 } else if (  statusText === '' ) {
     $(this).text("Available" )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="inbox appList" cellspacing="0" data-openonpick="False" id="cpC_gvSearchResult" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
   <thead>
      <tr class="inboxHeader">
         <th data-field="ApplicationId" scope="col"> Id</th>
         <th data-field="ApplicantFirstName" scope="col">First Name</th>
         <th data-field="CurrentQueue" scope="col">Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="inboxRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">1</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">DataSubmission</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inboxAltRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">2</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inboxRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">3</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">DataSubmission</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="inboxAltRow closedApp">
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">4</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
         <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three issues:

1. `$("#id tr")` will get all rows, so `td:eq(n)` will always find just the first one as it's tds across all rows not just the one in the loop.

Simplest fix without changing any other code is `$("#id tr").eq(i)`

2. you want td `:eq(2)` as it's 0-based, so (2) = 3rd col.

Giving

```
for(var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
{
  var status = $("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr").eq(i).find("td:eq(2)").text();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pyfxLc2w/

3. your `else` checks for `''` but you have `&nbsp;` which is not `''`

if you debug it in your fiddle, it's `==' '`

---

In general, rather than make a selection and property (eg `$("tr").length` and `$("tr").find(..).text()` - make the selection and keep that selection in a variable, *then* get the property,  This makes this so much easier in your code, eg:

```
var td = $("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr").eq(i).find("td:eq(2)");
if (td.text() == "DataSubmission")
   td.text("In Progress")
else
   td.text("Available")
```

without needing to rehash the selectors

---

Also note that jquery works with collections as a whole, so your entire code could just be:

```
$("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:contains('DataSubmission')").html("In Progress");
$("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:containsExact(' ')").html("Available");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462608/2181514) to add a `:containsExact` filter

---

If you want more control that `:contains` gives you, then you can use `.html()` overload that also works on a jquery collection (no need for loops)

You need `.html()` in order to access the `&nbsp;`, and in my testing `.trim()` didn't remove it.  If it was just whitespace, you could use `.text((i, txt) =>`.

Note, with `:nth-child`, it's 1-based, so now does need to be (3), not (2).

```
$("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:nth-child(3)").html((i, txt) => {
  return txt == "DataSubmission" 
  ? "In Progress" 
  : txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '') == "" 
    ? "Available" 
    : txt
});
```

```js
$("#cpC_gvSearchResult tr td:nth-child(3)").html((i, txt) => {
  return txt == "DataSubmission" 
  ? "In Progress" 
  : txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '') == "" 
    ? "Available" 
    : txt
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="inbox appList" cellspacing="0" data-openonpick="False" id="cpC_gvSearchResult" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="inboxHeader">
      <th data-field="ApplicationId" scope="col"> Id</th>
      <th data-field="ApplicantFirstName" scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th data-field="CurrentQueue" scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="inboxRow closedApp">
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">1</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">DataSubmission</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inboxAltRow closedApp">
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">2</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inboxRow closedApp">
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">3</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">DataSubmission</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inboxAltRow closedApp">
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Application Id">4</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Entity / Individual First Name" data-sid="al_Cust05">Dummy Name</td>
      <td class="inboxCol" data-title="Status" data-sid="al_ApplicantFirstName">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```